# Weblogic upgrade - authentication failure

Tags: java, authentication, weblogic, weblogic12c

Recently, I upgraded weblogic for my application from **version 10.3.5 to 12.1.1**. But since then, authentication of my application is failing.

I enabled authentication debugging in the WL console with WL10 and WL12 to compare and contrast a successful login.

In the **WL 10, Success**, case it would appear that the LDAP authentication fails but then continues on to authenticate via the Realm Adapter (gives Realm Adapter Commit) as per below:

```
####<2014-10-06 13:34:45.297 EDT> <Debug> <SecurityAtn>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '56' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1412616885297> <BEA-000000> <javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090302]Authentication Failed: User administrator denied
     at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:229)
              …. 
####<2014-10-06 13:34:45.297 EDT> <Debug> <SecurityAtn>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '56' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1412616885297> <BEA-000000> <com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.commit> 
####<2014-10-06 13:34:45.297 EDT> <Debug> <SecurityAtn>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '56' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1412616885297> <BEA-000000> <Realm Adapter Commit> 
####<2014-10-06 13:34:45.297 EDT> <Debug> <SecurityAtn>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '56' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1412616885297> <BEA-000000> <Realm Adapter Principal Added>
```

vs the **WL 12, Failure** (gives Realm Adapter Abort), case shown below:

```
####<2014-10-06 14:51:38.397 EDT> <Debug> <SecurityAtn>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '57' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1412621498397> <BEA-000000> <javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090302]Authentication Failed: User administrator denied
     at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:229)
              …. 
####<2014-10-06 14:51:38.397 EDT> <Debug> <SecurityAtn>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '57' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1412621498397> <BEA-000000> <com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.commit> 
####<2014-10-06 14:51:38.398 EDT> <Debug> <SecurityAtn>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '57' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1412621498398> <BEA-000000> <Realm Adapter Abort>
####<2014-10-06 14:51:38.398 EDT> <Debug> <SecurityAtn>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '57' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1412621498398> <BEA-000000> <com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.commit delegated, returning false>
```

the LDAP authentication fails and subsequent actions with the Realm Adapter appear to fail as well.

I am trying to login with **admin** user but I can see, **anonymous** in exception, I don't know what does that mean.

*Exception I got is :*

```
####<2014-10-06 14:53:38.829 EDT> <Error> <EMSServerLog>  <OCServer1> <ExecuteThread: '119' for queue: 'EjbExecuteQueue'> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-00C90044E2189AE73037> <> <1412621618829> <BEA-000000> <<com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminEJB_t45akl_Impl> ExecuteThread: '119' for queue: 'EjbExecuteQueue': 
java.rmi.RemoteException: Error authenticating user; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminBean.authenticate(SecurityUserAdminBean.java:1453)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminBean.authenticatea(SecurityUserAdminBean.java:2304)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminBean.login(SecurityUserAdminBean.java:314)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminEJB_t45akl_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:32)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminEJB_t45akl_EOImpl.login(Unknown Source)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminEJB_t45akl_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:695)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:520)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:516)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteRequestAdapter.execute(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:21)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.security.acl.DefaultUserInfoImpl.equalsCertificatesOnly(DefaultUserInfoImpl.java:218)
    at weblogic.security.acl.DefaultUserInfoImpl.equalsInAllButName(DefaultUserInfoImpl.java:198)
    at weblogic.security.acl.CachingRealm$CaseInsensitiveUserInfo.equals(CachingRealm.java:2036)
    at weblogic.security.acl.TTLCache.findEntry(TTLCache.java:525)
    at weblogic.security.acl.TTLCache.get(TTLCache.java:372)
    at weblogic.security.acl.CachingRealm.authenticate(CachingRealm.java:805)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminBean.authenticate(SecurityUserAdminBean.java:1422)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminBean.authenticate(SecurityUserAdminBean.java:1442)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminBean.authenticatea(SecurityUserAdminBean.java:2304)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminBean.login(SecurityUserAdminBean.java:314)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminEJB_t45akl_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:32)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminEJB_t45akl_EOImpl.login(Unknown Source)
    at com..system.dataManager.security.SecurityUserAdminEJB_t45akl_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:695)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:520)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:516)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteRequestAdapter.execute(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:21)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
```

Did anybody else face same issue? What could be possible solution for this problem?

Comment: You can try and reset the admin password for your domain via the instructions here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/reset-the-adminserver-password-in-weblogic-11g-and-12c.php Another thing you could try is deleting the `<domain home>/servers/<admin server name>/data/ldap` folder. This will force weblogic to recreate it and hopefully fix the embedded ldap